# NHibernate error accessing Informix database - System error occurred in network function

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, informix

I'm having a problem communicating with the Informix database using NHibernate, for a limited time works, but pass that particular time the error happens.

Follow the evidence below:

```
NHibernate.TransactionException: Begin failed with SQL exception ---> IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException: ERROR [08S01] [Informix .NET provider]Communication link failure.
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.BeginTransactionObject(IsolationLevel isolevel)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolevel)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolevel)
   em NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   em NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin()
   em NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction()

NHibernate.TransactionException: Begin failed with SQL exception ---> IBM.Data.Informix.IfxException: ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]System error occurred in network function. 
   em IBM.Data.Informix.DBCWrapper..ctor(IfxConnection connection)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnectionPool.IfxConnPoolNode..ctor(IfxConnection connection)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnectionPool.OpenNewConnection(IfxConnection connection, ConnectionPoolType ConnPoolType)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnectionPool.Open(IfxConnection connection)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnPoolManager.Open(IfxConnection connection)
   em IBM.Data.Informix.IfxConnection.Open()
   em NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   em NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection()
   em NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Connection()
   em NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   em NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin()
   em NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.BeginTransaction()
   em nddConnect.Client.EntryDocumentsComponent.NHibernate.Context.NHibernateSessionManager.Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
   em Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InterceptionBehaviorPipeline.Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, InvokeInterceptionBehaviorDelegate target)
   em DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_IComponentFacade_b83011052f234f2b9e18ae4d34bd90cc.CaptureJobConfig(IDictionary`2 dicEntryConfigJob)
   em Connect.Client.EntryDocumentsComponent.Controller.EntryJobController.GetJob(Guid transportActionGuid);
```

I tried various methods to simulate the error, but all to no avail.

I'm thinking it's a possible latency in the database after that getting something "stuck" in the section.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studies in the customer environment and logs it was found that the error occurred due to completion of a backup in a certain schedule that caused instability in the bank resulting in connection error and after that the the application did not work properly need to be restarted (the service), grateful for the help

Answer (score 0):

You may use DB2 Entity Framework driver to connect Informix server. 
(No Entity Framework support by using Informix native .NET driver)
(At IDS server you may need to configure DRDA port to use DB2 EF driver)
By using this driver you will be able to use LINQ commands .
LINQ is one of the alternate for NHibernate.